# How to drop Pandas dataframe columns based on another boolean array's column values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to drop the columns of a Pandas Dataframe **based on the value of the columns of a second Boolean array** (that has the same length).

For example suppose the pandas dataframe

```
[value1, value2, value3]
```

and a boolean array

```
[True, False, True].
```

The result of the dropping operation on the Pandas dataframe would be

```
[value1, value3]
```

Notice that we dropped the second column that has value False on the boolean array.

I guess something like this would work fine:

```
for i in range(len(boolean_array)):
    if boolean_array[i] == False:
        df = df.drop(df.columns[i], axis=1)
```

but I am pretty sure there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter columns by boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[1,2],
                   'value2':[10,20],
                   'value3':[100,200]})

arr = np.array([True, False, True])

df1 = df.loc[:, arr]
print (df1)
   value1  value3
0       1     100
1       2     200
```